# Converting 6-hr Time Increments to 12-hr Increments Using wgrib2

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix, grep

I'm currently having an issue where I'm trying to convert a grib2 data file with 6-hour time increments to 12-hour time increments using the method below:

```
wgrib2 gefs.20140626.t00z_6hrly_apcp.grib2 | grep APCP | sed 's/-/:/' | sort -t: -k5,5 -k4,4 -k3,3 -kn6,6 -kn7,7 | wgrib2 -i gefs.20140626.t00z_6hrly_apcp.grib2 -ncep_norm gefs.20140626.t00z_12hrly_apcp.grib2
```

I keep getting the following error whenever I try to run the code:

```
sort: invalid number at field start: invalid count at start of ‘n6,6’
```

Not sure how many users on here have experience using wgrib2 but, figured that I would give it a shot!

Comment: You want `-k6n,6` -- the sort "type" must follow the field.

Comment: Thanks Glenn! It's running now.